# Changing resolution doesn't affect image size in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, resolution

I am trying to change resolution in Photoshop but no changes appear. No change to size. For example I set resolution to 300 or even 1 but the size remains as before. It worked well before. Is there an option that turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have "Resample Image" unchecked.

Your image resolution (PPI) in and of itself is only meta-data, it doesn't actually affect the size of your image. If you actually want to change the size of your image, not only it's PPI value, then you need to resample the image.

[image]

*Note, your "Image Size" dialog may look different, I believe it changed in CC, I still use CS6—but the option will be the same (or similar).*

Comment: should i set re-sampling mode to nearest neighbors?

Comment: Depends what you want. Nearest neighbor will give you hard jagged edges, you most likely want one of the "Bicubic" options.